# No Provider for FormBuilder

Tags: angular

I'm still new to this and learning via tutorials, but for some reason i'm getting the message `No provider for formbuilder` when trying to test unique username.
I'm not sure why i'm getting this message, but i'm unable to find a solution. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

signup-component.ts

```ts
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ControlGroup, Control, Validators, FormBuilder} from '@angular/common'
import {UsernameValidators} from './usernameValidators'

@Component({
selector: 'signup',
templateUrl: 'signup-component.html'

})
export class SignupComponent{
  form: ControlGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder){
    this.form = fb.group({
      username:['', Validators.compose([
          Validators.required, UsernameValidators.cannotContainSpace
      ])],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }
}
```

usernameValidators.ts

```ts
import {Control} from '@angular/common'


export class UsernameValidators{

  static shouldBeUnique(control: Control){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(function(){
        if(control.value == "andy")
          resolve({shouldBeUnique: true});
        else
          resolve(null);
      }, 1000);

    });

  }


  static cannotContainSpace(control: Control){
    if (control.value.indexOf(' ') >= 0)
      return {cannotContainSpace: true};

    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 285, accepted):

Import `ReactiveFormsModule` and `FormsModule`

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
      BrowserModule /* or CommonModule */, 
      FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  ...
})
```

in the module where you're using `FormBuilder`

Comment: Thanks! it worked, I imported ReactiveFormsModule in app.module.ts as this was missing

Comment: ReactiveFormsmodule and FormsModule should not be imported together in the same module

Comment: @dag Why? `6 more to go...`

Comment: Why FormBuilder is not required to be added to providers in NgModule? Does Angular manages this dependency automatically?

Comment: If you add `ReactiveFormsModule` to `imports: [...]`, then it will be added to global providers https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8fb34bcd4383f1fc147ddf52db1777f9f9d75719/packages/forms/src/form_providers.ts#L35-L38

Comment: @DAG Could you maybe explain why those two should not be imported in the same module?

Comment: As you can read in this github issue, you can run both modules together: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10925

Comment: i had to import this into app.module.ts to get this working ... annoying as it bloats initial page loads - altho saying that i didn't notice much slow down in page load speeds

Comment: It's worth-mentioning that `ReactiveFormsModule` should be imported from the root (`app`) module. I tried to import it from one of the child modules, inside which a reactive form was actually used, and still got this error.

Comment: it's still giving the same error