# Angular - No provider for FormBuilder

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular 9.

I am getting the following error:

> No provider for FormBuilder

It has been reported in many cases, and the general solution appears to be to add the `FormsModule` to the `app.module.ts` file.

e.g.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

  imports: [
    FormsModule
```

I have tried this, but am still getting the error.

> ```
> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[FormBuilder -> FormBuilder -> FormBuilder]:
>
>   NullInjectorError: No provider for FormBuilder!
> NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[FormBuilder -> FormBuilder -> FormBuilder]: 
>   NullInjectorError: No provider for FormBuilder!
> ```

**Question**

Am I maybe doing something that's changed in Angular 9?  What do I need to do to fix this?

My code:

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: [''],
      password: ['']
    });
  }

  get f() { return this.loginForm.controls; }

  login() {
    this.authService.login(
      {
        username: this.f.username.value,
        password: this.f.password.value
      }
    )
    .subscribe(success => {
      if (success) {
        this.router.navigate(['/secret-random-number']);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './auth/containers/login/login.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ApprovalListComponent } from './approval-list/component/approval-list.component';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableExporterModule } from 'mat-table-exporter';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ApprovalListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableExporterModule
  ],
  providers: [LoginComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You need to use `ReactiveFormsModule` to use form builder. `FormsModule` is not enough. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Provider for FormBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249065/no-provider-for-formbuilder)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

form builder is  `ReactiveFormsModule`

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule
```

you'll also need this module to use `formGroup` and `formControl` directives.

Answer (score 6):

in my case resolved by these steps:

first add this into app.module.ts

```
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
```

second add **FormBuilder**:

```
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    FormBuilder,
```

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this by adding both `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` in `app.module.ts` (I was missing `ReactiveFormsModule`):

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

  imports: [

    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
```

Comment: just an fyi, you only need the `FormsModule` if you're using `ngModel` or template driven forms. If you're just using reactive / model driven forms, you don't need to import that module. I usually stick to one form style per project, personally, but that's more a matter of preference.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I forgot to import `FormsModule`, `ReactiveFormsModule` in the main parent `app.module.ts` module file

```
imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule

],
```

also, Add in your current module file.

`sub.module.ts` add `FormsModule`, `ReactiveFormsModule`

```
imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule

],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
      providers: [
        FormBuilder
      ],
    })...
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Consider adding an explanation to your code, since that will be more helpful.